# How to have a strict order in queued listeners? Is this possible in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Currently, I'm firing an event, when a user needs to be deleted. For example:

```
'App\Events\DeleteUserWasCalled' => [
   'App\Listeners\User\DeleteUserImages',
   'App\Listeners\User\RemoveFromMailchimp',
   'App\Listeners\User\RemoveFromStripe',
   'App\Listeners\User\RemoveOffers',
   'App\Listeners\User\UpdateRelatedTablesToNull',
   'App\Listeners\User\SoftDeleteUser',
],
```

All those listeners are implementing ShouldQueue. But my problem is that the queue is not in the correct order. For example `'App\Listeners\User\SoftDeleteUser'` is processed before `'App\Listeners\User\RemoveFromMailchimp'`.

`RemoveFromMailchimp`needs the user's email but in `SoftDeleteUser` it is set to `Null`.

One solution comes into my mind is to use a job class and put everything in one class. But it feels not nice for me.

Any idea how to fix it? The order that I have listed is important (especially the last two listeners)

**Edit**

```
class DeleteUserWasCalled
{
    use SerializesModels;

    public $user;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have access to the model id inside the listener? You could use `withTrashed()` to get the soft deleted model

Comment: @TravisBritz yes I have the id and I can get the trashed model, but in SoftDeleteUser I'm not only soft-deleting the user but I set all attributes to `Null`. So it does not matter, I won't get the right email. Of course, I could copy the email in the event class, but I'm interested in a better way.

Comment: If you're deleting data that you'll need later, you should either pass that data to the event or wait to delete it. For example, you could have a scheduled task for setting attributes to null which runs regularly and clears records where deleted_at is older than an hour

Comment: @TravisBritz hmm I like the idea with a scheduled task. However, technically the GDPR writes the information should be deleted immediately (I live in Germany...). Besides that, it would be cool to delete the data as soon as possible, since the user might want to create a new account with the same email but in the DB email is set to unique.

Comment: In that case passing the user data directly to the event might be the best option, and your listeners can get the user data from the event payload rather than from the database

Comment: @TravisBritz Oh no you know what! I'm stupid! I already saved the payload, but I thought that the payload is changed due to a listener. But I had just a typo. It's not `$event->user->mail` it's `$event->user->email`. That it is why it was null. Thank you for your help!